# Page is not refreshing after I click a button with selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium

This is the workflow I'm trying to achieve:
- Load doordash.com
- Enter the address
- Hit the find restaurants
- Scroll to the end of the page and the names of all the restaurants

My script right now enters the address and seems to hit the find restaurants button but the page after that does not load for some reason

```
from sys import platform
import sys
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
from urllib import urlretrieve
import zipfile
import time
import os
import datetime
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import os
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

class Scrapper:
    def __init__(self):
        self.profiles = {}
        if platform == "linux" or platform == "linux2":
            print "Fetching Linux Path Variables"
            self.OS = "linux64"

        elif platform == "darwin":
            print "Fetching Mac Path Variables"
            self.OS = "mac64"

    elif platform == "win32":
        print "Fetching Windows Path Variables"
        self.OS = "win32"

        if not os.path.isfile("driver/chromedriver"): 
            self.fetchChromeDriver(self.OS)
            if platform == "linux" or platform == "linux2" or platform == "darwin":
                os.system("chmod a+x driver/chromedriver")
        self.chromedriverPath = "driver/chromedriver"

def fetchChromeDriver(self, OS):
    print("Downloading Chromedriver")
    self.createFolders("driver/")
    localZipPath = "driver/{}.zip".format(OS)
    urlretrieve("https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.35/chromedriver_{}.zip".format(OS), localZipPath)
    zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(localZipPath, 'r')
    zip_ref.extractall("driver/")
    zip_ref.close()
    os.remove(localZipPath)

def createFolders(self, path):
    if(not os.path.isdir(path)):
        os.makedirs(path)

def downloadPage(self,url):
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_driver = self.chromedriverPath 
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path=chrome_driver)
        driver.get(url)
        elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located(
        (By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Enter your delivery address']")))
        elem.send_keys('2 Pierce Ave, San Jose')
        elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        time.sleep(2)
        elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[contains(@class, 'Autocomplete_suggestionButton_')]")
        elements[0].click()
        button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Find Restaurants"]')
        button.click()
        time.sleep(20)



def main():
    scrapper = Scrapper()
    scrapper.downloadPage('https://www.doordash.com/food-delivery/')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if you add another  `elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)` between `time.sleep(2)` and `elements = ...` in your definition of `downloadPage`, it goes to the next page for me.

Hope it works for you

Answer (score 0):

You just need to wait for 'Find Restaurants' button to become clickable. Here:

```
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Find Restaurants"]')))
button.click()
```

Good luck!